# How to remove Celery Task results from Django Admin in production

Tags: python-3.x, django, celery, django-celery

I am currently working with `Django Celery` and I have integrated `Django celery backend` for managing my background tasks. I want to remove `Task Results` tab from `CELERY RESULTS` section but could not find any help online.

Image for reference:

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: Import this model in `admin.py` and use `admin.site.unregister(TaskResults)`

Comment: @Crosby I have the idea but cannot find the model from the celery package, any lead to that would be awesome.

Comment: If you are using `django-celery-results`: `from django_celery_results.models import TaskResults'`

Comment: Added, but got this problem:
`django.contrib.admin.sites.NotRegistered: The model TaskResult is not registered
`

Comment: What if you register it before unregistering?

Comment: I cannot find a proper module which I can register and then unregister :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
If you get

> The model TaskResult is not registered

error import from `django_celery_results.admin`.

```
from django_celery_results.admin import TaskResult, GroupResult
admin.site.unregister(TaskResult)
admin.site.unregister(GroupResult)
```

Answer (score 3):

I inserted some code on `admin.py` of any app what register after `django_celery_results` app as follows.

```
from django_celery_results.models import TaskResult
admin.site.unregister(TaskResult)
```