# How to register django-import-export-celery on a custom adminsite

Tags: django-admin, django-import-export, django-import-export-celery

I'm building an app that use only django admin. I'm using two different adminsite in two different url, say admin and myadmin. I've installed django-import-export and django-import-export-celery because I need to upload big csv files. The problem arises when I try to use django-import-export-celery in myadmin. Following the readme of the plugin the models work perfectly in the usual admin, but not in myadmin.

In the admin.py file there is the resource as required by django-import-export

```
admin.py
class MyappAdminSite(AdminSite):
    ....
myadmin_site = MyappAdminSite(name='alma_admin')

class AlmaResource(resources.ModelResource):
     .....
class AlmaAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    resource_classes = [AlmaResource]
    .....
myadmin_site.register(AlmaModel, AlmaAdmin)
```

I do not know how to change the following settings that are perfect for the usual admin dashboard.

```
settings.py

def resource():
    from myapp.admin import AlmaResource
    return AlmaResource


IMPORT_EXPORT_CELERY_MODELS = {
    "AlmaModel": {
        'app_label': 'myapp',
        'model_name': 'AlmaModel',
        'resource': resource,
    }
}

IMPORT_EXPORT_CELERY_INIT_MODULE = "my_project.celery"
BROKER_URL = "redis://localhost:6379"
```

I've tried fancy way of importing but I'm not able to register the class. This is what I would like to do

```
admin.py
from import_export_celery.models.exportjob import ExportJob
from import_export_celery.models.importjob import ImportJob

myadmin_site.register(ImportJob, AlmaModel)
```

but I've found only errors. My aim is to keep separate the usual admin, devoted to managing users and groups, and myadmin where you should be able to import/export file using celery.

Answer (score 0):

Following this answer [How to remove Celery Task results from Django Admin in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65956441/how-to-remove-celery-task-results-from-django-admin-in-production) the correct way to proceed is

```
admin.py

from import_export_celery.models.exportjob import ExportJob
from import_export_celery.models.importjob import ImportJob

myadmin_site.register(ImportJob)
myadmin_site.register(ExportJob)


admin.site.unregister(ImportJob)
admin.site.unregister(ExportJob)
```